# (C#) How to list all user-inputted integers in an array?

Tags: c#

I'm working on an application that has the user choose how many integers to enter into an array, and then has them input the numbers to be added to the array. After each number is inputted, it shows all non-duplicate integers entered by the user up to that point in a vertical list.  If it isn't unique, it informs the user that it has already been inputted.

I'm not sure how to make the application list every integer entered, rather than just the most recent one.

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    //checks how many numbers will be entered
    int manyNumbers;
    Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
    manyNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] array = new int[manyNumbers];
    //starts asking for numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < manyNumbers;) 
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter number: ");
        string entered = Console.ReadLine();
        int val;
        //checks to see if valid number
        if (!Int32.TryParse(entered, out val))
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid number '{0}'", entered);
            array[i++] = val;
        }
        //checks to see if already entered
        else if (i > 0 && array.Take(i).Contains(val))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} has already been entered", val);
            array[i++] = val;
        }
        //prints inputted integer
        else {
            array[i++] = val;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", val);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the array so far printing each.

Forgive my mobile crafted code, but more or less this:

```
//prints inputted integer
 else { 
      array[i++] = val;
      for(int j=0 ; j<i;j++) {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}", array[j]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it isn't printing any integers. Could there be an error somewhere?

Comment: Ya sorry, typed it on my phone. Mistyped the loop check. Should be j<i not greater than. Try my fixed post

Comment: Thanks. That works a lot better, but is there a way to avoid showing duplicates in the printed integers without removing them from the array?

Comment: Not performantly. How ever if you are sure this will only be a few numbers, the linq distinct() extension method will eliminate duplicates easily

Answer (score 0):

Very Basic approach, try one of the following:

```
for(var x=0;x<array.length;x++)
```

or

```
foreach(var i in array)
```

But your use case, use [HashSet data structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Mathematically, Set is unique list of things.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `foreach` loop

```
foreach(int num in array)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", num);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code, it uses a Dictionary to keep the list in memory and to search to see if the an integer has been added,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //checks how many numbers will be entered
        int manyNumbers;
        Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter?");
        manyNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Dictionary<int, int> array = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        //starts asking for numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < manyNumbers; )
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter number: ");
            string entered = Console.ReadLine();
            int val;

            //checks to see if valid number
            if (!Int32.TryParse(entered, out val)) 
            {
                Console.Write("Invalid number '{0}'", entered);
            }
            //checks to see if already entered
            else 
            if (i > 0 && array.ContainsKey(val)) 
            {
                Console.Write("{0} has already been entered", val);
                //array[i++] = val;
            }
            else
            {
                //* add the new integer to list
                array.Add(val, 0);

               //prints the complete list
                List<int> keys = new List<int>(array.Keys);
                Console.WriteLine();
                for(int j=0; j<keys.Count; j++) Console.WriteLine(keys[j]);
            }                          




        }

    }
```

Comment: This is way over complicating things, and although the list is likely to be small this is really inefficient.